# Elasticsearch/tire Nested Queries with persistant objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, tire

I'm trying to use Tire to perform a nested query on a persisted model. The model (Thing) has Tags and I'm looking to find all Things tagged with a certain Tag

```
class Thing
  include Tire::Model::Callbacks
  include Tire::Model::Persistence

  index_name { "#{Rails.env}-thing" }

  property :title, :type => :string
  property :tags, :default => [], :analyzer => 'keyword', :class => [Tag], :type => :nested
end
```

The nested query looks like

```
class Thing 
   def self.find_all_by_tag(tag_name, args)
      self.search(args) do
         query do
            nested path: 'tags' do
               query do
                  boolean do
                     must { match 'tags.name', tag_name }
                 end
               end
            end
         end
      end 
   end 
 end
```

When I execute the query I get a "not of nested type" error

```
Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{\"query\":{\"nested\":{\"query\":{\"bool\":{\"must\":[{\"match\":{\"tags.name\":{\"query\":\"TestTag\"}}}]}},\"path\":\"tags\"}},\"size\":10,\"from\":0,\"version\":true}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[test-thing] [nested] nested object under path [tags] is not of nested type]; }]","status":500}
```

Looking at the source for Tire it seems that mappings are created from the options passed to the "property" method, so I don't think I need a separate "mapping" block in the class. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

Following Karmi's answer below, I recreated the index and verified that the mapping is correct:

```
thing: {
  properties: {
    tags: {
      properties: {
        name: {
          type: string
        }
        type: nested
      }
    }
    title: {
      type: string
    }
   }
```

However, when I add new Tags to Thing

```
thing = Thing.new
thing.title = "Title"
thing.tags << {:name => 'Tag'}
thing.save
```

The mapping reverts to "dynamic" type and "nested" is lost.

```
thing: {
  properties: {
    tags: {
      properties: {
        name: {
          type: string
        }
        type: "dynamic"
      }
    }
    title: {
      type: string
    }
   }
```

The query fails with the same error as before. How do I preserve the nested type when adding new Tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, indeed, the mapping configuration in `property` declarations is passed on in the Persistence integration.

In a situation like this, there's always the and and only first question: **how does the mapping look like for real**?

So, use eg. the `Thing.index.mapping` method or the Elasticsearch's REST API: `curl localhost:9200/things/_mapping` to have a look.

Chances are, that your index was created with the dynamic mapping, based on the JSON you have used, and you have changed the mapping later. In this case, the index creation logic is skipped, and the mapping is not what you expect.

---

There's a *Tire* [issue](https://github.com/karmi/tire/issues/161) opened about displaying warning when the index mapping is different from the mapping defined in the model.

Comment: thank you very much for your help, and an excellent library. I'm still having issues preserving the nested document type when adding new tags. I've updated the question with details, can you shed any light?

Comment: I got this working, thank you. I had to call Thing.create_elasticsearch_index in the setup of each test to make sure that the mapping was properly created.